# How do I disable modules / add-ons manually?

Tags: module, ee1, blank-screen

I migrated the site over to a new server and a new domain. Now I'm getting a blank page on the Modules page.

How do I disable each one individually until I identify the culprit?

I tried enabled error reporting but I get nothing.

Edit: I'm on EE 1.6

Answer (score 1):

I've experienced this issue frequently and usually find its because one of the configuration paths has not been setup correctly on the new server.

As such I always install [Deeploy Helper](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/deeploy-helper) before migrating. Then, after migrating to the new server, if I get a blank Modules page I'll copy the Deeploy Helper URI from the previous sites CP and paste into the new sites CP. After Deeploy Helper's module page loads I update the paths/URIs and it resolves the issue.

If you're unwilling or unable to use Deeploy Helper in the manner suggested I'd start by concentrating on ensuring all your [paths & URIs](http://ee1docs.com/installation/masked_cp_access.html) are correct.

Comment: Agreed - Deeploy Helper is crucial for migrating EE 1.6 where less configuration was available outside of the Control Panel. That said, I jumped on a legacy project recently, and the currently available version of DH wasn't compatible with older versions.